# High Charts not showing for user, source code is being loaded correctly

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a page which uses high charts to generate graphs of data stored in a MySQL database.

One user is reporting that for them and a couple of other users in their office, the graphs are not present on the page.

- There are no errors appearing in the error logs
- Initially I thought it may be an issue with MySQL requests being too slow, so I inserted a buffering page to load all that data, put it in an array and then draw the graphs from that.
- I asked the user to save the source code of the page as a text file and send it to me: when I load that page suing that code everything is normal (and all the graphs are there correctly).
- The user can view other high charts generated pages elements
- I have the latest version of high charts
- It is not browser specific, he experiences this across IE9 Chrome and FF (whereas other users (90% of them) can view them fine in all browsers.

I have no idea where to go next debugging something like this - it seems as though it must be something specific to his set up, but I can't think what considering he's able to view other pages drawn using high charts fine.

For what it is worth, here are some relevant parts of the source code:

Page head:

```
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.myurl.org/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.myurl.org/js/exporting.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.myurl.org/js/jquery.bpopup-0.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Management Data - Key Indicators</title>
<base href="https://www.myurl.org/" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.myurl.org/css/style.css" />


</head>
```

An example of the HighCharts jquery:

```
(function($){ // encapsulate jQuery 
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart2a',
                type: 'column'  
            },

            credits: {
            enabled: false
             },
             legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',

                floating: false,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            title: {
                align: 'left',
                style: {fontSize: '12px'},
                text: 'Country objectives by region: 2012'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['EAPRO','ESARO','MENA','TACRO','ROSA','WCARO']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage by objective'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.series.name +': '+ Math.round(this.y)+'%'; 
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
                series: [ {

                name: 'Advocacy and Planning',
                data: [11.1,0,16.7,0,14.3,0]
            },{

                name: 'Pilot & early implementation',
                data: [33.3,5.6,16.7,0,14.3,5.6]
            },{

                name: 'Limited service provision',
                data: [55.6,11.1,0,0,14.3,16.7]
            },{ 

                name: 'Expanded service provision',
                data: [0,83.3,66.7,100,57.1,77.8]
            }]
        });
    });

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Any ideas about where to look / what to test next would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are any of these end users on a proxy server? A url like `ajax.googleapis.com` could be getting blocked, meaning no jquery, and therefore no charts. What happens if you load jquery via `www.myurl.org`?

Comment: Hmm, I'm fairly sure other jQuery elements are working fine, but I have adjusted this and am checking with those in question (they are indeed behind a proxy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this was because of an https issue: I was serving the highercharts code on an insecure server, so none of the elements were being loaded. Answering in case anyone else happens to have done the same thing!